# R create ggplot2 facet_wrap using wide data frame only

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

practicing mtcars, ggplot2, facet_wrap, pivot_longer etc. I'm trying to learn how to create a ggplot2 facet_wrap graph using a long data frame - what does that code look like in ggplot2?

You can see I've created a histogram of one of the numeric variables:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 32, color = 'black', fill = 'lightblue')
```

[image]

And here I select the numeric variables and turn the data frame into a long data frame:

```
mtcars_numeric <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec) 

mtcars_long_numeric <- pivot_longer(mtcars_numeric, names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 2:6)
```

And here I graph the long data frame with a facet_wrap.

```
ggplot(mtcars_long_numeric, aes(x = values, color = names)) +
  facet_wrap(~names, scales = 'free') +
  geom_histogram(bins = 32, color = 'black', fill = 'lightblue')
```

[image]

I'm just asking this question to better understand R and ggplot2. What would the code look like to create a facet_wrap graph like the one right above, but only using the mtcars data frame and not using the long data frame that I created using the tidyr::pivot_longer verb? I'm just trying to understand the logic of this ggplot2 grammar, the process, the kind of trouble that a long data frame would save going into ggplot2. I already know how to turn a data frame into a long data frame and then pivot off that value -- I understand that I'm trying to find a less optimal way to do something I already know how to do - I'm just trying to learn and get a larger view!

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = ?) +
  facet_wrap(~ ?, scales = 'free') +
  geom_histogram(bins = 32, color = 'black', fill = 'lightblue')
```

Comment: Relevant discussion [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3357), but tl;dr: it apparently was part of the original grammar of graphics but was not implemented in ggplot2.

Comment: `facet_wrap` uses a variable from the data set to define each facet, so I don't think it's even possible to do what you're saying. The alternative would be to make separate plots for each original column and then compose them together outside of ggplot, e.g. using grid or cowplot or pathwork packages.